# Soma de intervalos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Precisava de uma formula para calcular valores com intervalos.

Ou seja, tenho vários escalões:

> Entre 0 e 5 = 0,58€;
>
> Entre 6 e 10 = 0,64;
>
> Entre 11 e 15 = 1,05€;
>
> Acima de 15 = 1,46€.

Se o número for 7 por exemplo, tem de ser calculado da seguinte forma:

```
(5*0,58)+(2*0,64)
```

É por escalões. Conseguem ajudar?

Comment: Não sou o melhor conhecedor de Excel, mas creio que usando máximos e mínimos de consiga chegar nos escalões desejados. Tipo, `min($A1, 5) * 0.58 + max(min($A1-5, 10-5), 0) * 0.64` (sendo `$A1` uma célula com o argumento)

Comment: Creio que você pode fazer uma fórmula gigante com vários `SES()` ou utilizar um Solver com uma função objetivo do tipo: `FO= x_0 * 0,58 + x_1 * 0,64 + x_2 * 1,05 + x_3 * 1,46` se os valores forem crescentes ou decrescentes como no exemplo... e as restrições dos `x` com o intervalo desejado.

Comment: Vou dar o exemplo melhor a ver se me conseguem ajudar.

Luis - 8 m3
Pedro - 4 m3
Andre - 15 m3

O preço da água é calculado através destes escalões em seguida:

Entre 0 e 5 m3 = 0,58€
Entre 6 e 10 m3 = 0,64€
Entre 11 e 15 m3 = 1,05€

Então eu quero saber quanto cada um deles vai pagar de consumo de água conforme os escalões.

E o cálculo é feito da seguinte forma:

Luis consumiu 8 m3;

(5*0,58) + (3*0,64) = 4,82€

Pedro 4 m3;

4*0,58= 2,32 €;

Andre 15 m3; 

(5*0,58) + (5*0,64) + (5*1,05) = 11,35 €.

Eu agora queria uma formula para me calcular isto desta forma.

Comment: Entendi seu problema, só dei dicas de quais as possíveis maneiras de solucioná-las.

Comment: Tem que rever esses intervalos aí, se for `5.5` o valor cai no limbo. Provavelmente seria: `[0, 5[`, `[5, 10[`, `[10, 15[`... Ou `[0, 6[`, `6, 11[`, `[11, 16[`.

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema possui valores de maneira crescente da maneira que está proposto (0,58; 0,64; 1;05; 1,46), uma função de otimização para obter o mínimo resolve...

## Excel Solver

Para realizar estas tarefas sem a utilização do VBA ou uma fórmula gigantesca, o solver precisa ser utilizado e uma lógica simples é utilizada.

### Habilitar o Solver no Excel

A versão utilizada é o Excel 2010.

1. Entre no botão Office ou Arquivo.
2. Clique em **Opções**.
3. Clique em **Add-Ins**.
4. Instale o Solver Add-in e clique em Ok.

### Habilitar o Add-in

1. [Habilite o Modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba **Desenvolvedor**, clique em **Add-ins**
3. Uma janela irá abrir e o **Solver Add-in** deve ser marcado.

[image: Solver Add-in]

## Solver

Com os seguintes dados na planiha:

```
|   | A  |  B   |   C    |      D       |             E              |         F         |
|---|----|------|--------|--------------|----------------------------|-------------------|
| 1 |  0 | 0,58 | =A2-A1 |              | =SOMARPRODUTO(D1:D4;B1:B4) | =VALOR_QUANTIDADE |
| 2 |  5 | 0,64 | =A3-A2 |              |                            |                   |
| 3 | 10 | 1,05 | =A4-A3 |              |                            |                   |
| 4 | 15 | 1,46 |        |              |                            |                   |
| 5 |    |      |        | =SOMA(D1:D4) |                            |                   |
```

A seguinte função objetivo e restrições são adicionadas:

[image: ![FO]

[image: int]

[image: y]

[image: restricao]

[image: somatorio]

O solver é adicionado na célula `E1` com os seguintes parâmetros:

[image: Solver]

## Resultado

Para 4 m³:

[image: 4m3]

Para 8 m³:

[image: 8m3]

Para 15 m³:

[image: 15m3]

### Extra:

Para mudar a função de otimização, outras formas de função objetivo ou mais restrições podem ser adicionadas. Caso deseje se aprofundar no assunto procure por Programação Linear, Método Simplex ou Solver. Ou em inglês Linear Programming (LP), Simplex ou Linear Optimization. Uma boa ferramenta para o Excel de problemas de otimização é o [Solver Studio](http://solverstudio.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não sei se vai te ajudar totalmente, mas para intervalos (ranges) é bom fazer uma tabela com esses intervalos por exemplo: célula a1 = 0; b1= 0,58 , célula a2= 5 ; b2 = 0,58 , célula a3 = 6 ; b3 = 0,64 , a4 = 10 ; b4 = 0,64 e assim por diante. 
 Fazendo a tabela auxiliar , vc pode fazer um procv “VERDADEIRO” em vez de falso, pois com o verdadeiro vc pode puxar os intervalos da tabela, em vez de valores exatos. Isso pode te ajudar no seu racional de cálculos em “escalões” (classes de intervalos)

Comment: Olá @Diego. Tente estruturar melhor a sua resposta, está um pouco confusa.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fórmulas:

`C1:=ARREDMULTB.MAT(E1;5)/5`

`D1:=E1-(C1*5)`

`E2:=SE(C1=0;D1*B1;SE(C1=1;(B1*5)+(B2*D1);SE(C1=2;(B1*5)+(B2*5)+(B3*D1);SE(C1=3;(B1*5)+(B2*5)+(B3*5)+(B4*D1)))))`

Basta vc inserir o valor de consumo na célula E1

O único problema é que o intervalo de cobrança que vc determinou é fixo.